# Change class types in a list

Tags: r, list, class, lme4

I have run a series of "lmerModLmerTest" class-type models, which I have saved in a list. I would like to change the **class** of these models from "lmerModLmerTest" to "lmerTest".

For one model, I would change it like this, which works nicely:

```
class(model_1) <- "lmerMod"
```

However as I have many models I would ideally like to loop through the list in which I have saved all these models (old_models).

However when I run this code:

```
mylist.df <- lapply(names(old_models),
                   function(x){
                   b <- as(old_models[[x]],"lmerMod")
                   b
                   })
```

the resulting new list (mylist.df) has 0 elements. Any ideas as to why this is the case?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use names:

```r
library(lmerTest)
#> Loading required package: lme4
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lmerTest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmer
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
library(lme4)

old_models <- list(
  lmerTest::lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1|Species) , data = iris),
  lmerTest::lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + (1|Species) , data = iris)
)

old_models
#> [[1]]
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
#> Formula: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1 | Species)
#>    Data: iris
#> REML criterion at convergence: 194.6361
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  Species  (Intercept) 1.010   
#>  Residual             0.438   
#> Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      3.4062       0.7972  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
#> Formula: Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + (1 | Species)
#>    Data: iris
#> REML criterion at convergence: 71.8035
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  Species  (Intercept) 0.5706  
#>  Residual             0.2890  
#> Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
#> Fixed Effects:
#>  (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#>       1.0448        0.3444
sapply(old_models, class)
#> [1] "lmerModLmerTest" "lmerModLmerTest"

new_models <- lapply(old_models, function(x) as(x, "lmerMod"))
new_models
#> [[1]]
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1 | Species)
#>    Data: iris
#> REML criterion at convergence: 194.6361
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  Species  (Intercept) 1.010   
#>  Residual             0.438   
#> Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      3.4062       0.7972  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + (1 | Species)
#>    Data: iris
#> REML criterion at convergence: 71.8035
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  Species  (Intercept) 0.5706  
#>  Residual             0.2890  
#> Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
#> Fixed Effects:
#>  (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#>       1.0448        0.3444
sapply(new_models, class)
#> [1] "lmerMod" "lmerMod"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @danlooo thanks for the answer, when I do this I do, however, seem to lose the observations contained in the items of the list. So, before when I put in old_models[[1]] I would get the output of the model and when I wrapped this in the class function I would get this:
[1] "lmerModLmerTest"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lmerTest" 

now instead when I do mylist.df[[1]] I just get a character value saying "lmerMod" and seem to have lost the content

Comment: @covaova I revised my answer with explicit lmerModTest objects